# How to query AWS ElasticSearch Service (URI Search) with multiple query filters using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, python-requests

Strange behaviour of AWS when querying ElasticSearch with [Query String Syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) using python's requests.

```
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

...
aws_auth = AWS4Auth(access_key, secret_key, region, service, session_token=token)

res = requests.request(url=url, method=method, data=query, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, auth=aws_auth)

if not res.ok:
    print(res.text)

...
```

When there is only one filter or none everything works fine. E.g.:

```
GET log_index/_doc/_search?q=country_code:US
{
  "aggs": { ...}
}
```

=> OK

But when I add more queries it breaks with the error:

```
GET log_index/_doc/_search?q=country_code:(US OR CA)
{
  "aggs": { ...}
}
```

or

```
GET log_index/_doc/_search?q=country_code:US AND os:windows
{
  "aggs": { ...}
}
```

=> HTTP 403 **Error:**

**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

Does anyone have any ideas about how to 'fix' this problem?

**Note 1**: Without multiple queries, everything works as expected => it's not a problem with credentials.

**Note 2**: Running queries in a browser or in Kibana provides expected results => it' not a problem with queries.

**Note 3**: Have tried with and without url-encoding (*urllib.parse.quote*)

---

UPDATE:

- Disabling request authentication (by *removing auth=aws_auth*) and whitelisting IP helps
- Behaviour is the same with/without a request body

---

**Current solution/Workaround**:
After hours of debugging still no idea what the problem is. Queries were rewritten to request-body-only, e.g.:

```
GET log_index/_doc/_search
{
  "query": { "bool": { ... } },
  "aggs": { ... }
}
```

Everything works as expected, but constructing correct bool query is tricky.

Comment: Did you run `aws configure` properly ?

Comment: @Rubens_Z: AWS credentials are correct, authentication at ES Service and at other services work without problems